# Issues in using cheerio for scraping in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to crawl a webpage, containing a(anchor) tags of class group-link. In this code I am displaying all the links of this a tag on the console.

```
var http = require("https");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
 // Utility function that downloads a URL and invokes
 // callback with the data.
 function download(url, callback) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
             var data = "";
                 res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                           data += chunk;
                              });
                    res.on("end", function() {
                              callback(data);
                                  });
                      }).on("error", function() {
                              callback(null);
                                });
}
var url = "https://www.example.com"
download(url, function(data) {
    if (data) {
           var $ = cheerio.load(data);
  $("a.group-link").each(function(i, e) {
      console.log($(e).attr("href")); });
              }
                else console.log("error");  
});
```

But I am getting no output not even the error because if condition is satisfied.
For using JQuery in node.js, do we need to include anything?
Thanks.

Comment: the code provided seems basically correct. Test if your jQuery selectors are really correct. Also even though you are using basic selectors, be aware that cheerio supports only a subset of jQuery selectors.

Comment: actually the webpage i am crawling is having random thing in its source code inspite of having same elements as they are visible in inspect element

Comment: jQuery tag is not correct, you're using cheerio, as mentioned by @px1mp it's only supporting a subset of selectors. Test to test if you get correct object, use poor man's debugging: output whole data and output data returned by your selector. Or even better, if you're using an IDE like WebStorm, it's offering a debugger for nodejs.